# Trying to add 2nd site to apache2 (ubuntu 13.04 hosted on Amazon)

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, apache2

I am working remotely on a server that I accesss via ip address (amazon ec2)

I disabled the default site

```
a2dissite default
```

created a new directory to host the website and created new site-available to link it up

```
  a2ensite newsite
```

and everthing is working fine.

Now I want to add a 2nd site the same way

```
VirtualHost *:80>

#alias mysite "/var/www/site2/" #this doesnt seem to do anything

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/site2/
        <Directory /var/www/site2/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My conclusion that it seems as if whichever site-enabled comes first is the one that gets used. IS there anyway to add a 2nd site if the url is an IP? It seems like apache differentiates on the server name passed to it, but since Im only using an IP I can't do this.

ideally I would like it set up as follows

```
http://ip/site1 points to /var/www/site1
```

and

```
http://ip/site2 points to /var/www/site2
```

Suggestions? Thanks-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using the alias directive to get the desired behaviour, this link helped me get there:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `ServerName` parameter.

This is the most important parameter, even before DocumentRoot. On a Named based VirtualHosting system apache decides which VirtualHost will be used to answer an HTTP requests by comparing the `Host: www.example.com` HTTP Header in the request with the list of unique ServerName and multiples ServerAlis defined in his list of Virtualhosts.

When no match is found the default VH (first one in alphabetic order) is used.

Usually VirtualHosting is done this way and need a DNS record or host file alteration to be tested. The other way is IP-based VirtualHosting, witj one IP per VirtualHost.

And you can mix the two ways by using an IP (or several) instead of * in the NameVirtualHost general setting, and use them also in `VirtualHost` directives instead of the *. (* means all IPs).

Comment: I think I understand everything you've said. This is just a dev server so I dont have any servernames to use. I view the website by going to the ip address that Amazon has assigned to it (no dns).